# Import and use strike components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-field, custom, create-component

I'm new to salesforce development so this will be probably a very trivial question but I'm stuck here.

I'm trying to import and use [Strike lookup component](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeLookup)

So I have imported all the files in the needed folder and synched everything with my org.

Now as far as I have understood, I should be able to use this code:

```
<c:strike_lookup
label="Account"
object="Account"
searchField="Name"
placeholder="Select an option"
iconName="standard:account"
subtitleField="Industry"
order="Name"
limit="5"
loadingMessage="Loading..."
errorMessage="Invalid input"/>
```

Inside a lightning component.
But when I try to use this code, salesforce complain about strike lookup component not existing.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Sorry again for the trivial question, thanks!

Edit1: (for showing folder structures)

[image: Aura folder structure]
[image: Classes folder]

So those are my Aura and Classes folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have posted look correct, so a couple of other things to check...

We use `strike_lookup` and needed to include a few other "building block" strike components for it to work:

- defaultTokens
- strike_evt
- strike_svg
- strike_tooltip

If you have put the strike components in a separate part of your source tree, you will need to reference that location in your `sfdx-project.json` e.g.:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/wiz/main",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/wiz/test"
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/strike/main"
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/strike/test"
        }
    ],
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "43.0"
}
```

Best you use your browser's "Developer Tools" to look for the root cause too.

Comment: inside my aura folder I have placed: 
- dafaultTokens
- strike_evt
- strike_svg
- strike_tooltip

Inside my classes folder I have placed:
- strike_lookupController.cls
- strike_lookupController.cls-meta.xml
- strike_responseData.cls
- strike_responseData.cls-meta.xml
- strike_tst_lookupController.cls
- strike_tst_lookupController.cls-meta.xml
- strike_utilities.cls
- strike_utilities.cls-meta.xml

Now what I'm doing is from the developer console: 
- create a Lighting Component
- try to write <c: but the lookup component from strike is not present

Comment: Sorry for the formatting I though I could go to the next line even in the comment.
Actually I do not have sfdx-project.json in my Force.com IDE, could be this the problem?

Comment: @ZenoTrevisan All I can suggest is the "Developer Tools" They have various tabs where you can see failed network requests and JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had actually two separates problem.

The first is that I had imported all the dependencies but I forgot to import the actual strike_lookup component.

The second was that the order on which I uploaded the files on the org server was wrong, meaning that eclipse did not upload the file because of other missing files (which were selected to be synched but probably after that file) so given the error, it did not upload all the files.

Sorry again people!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. You don't have to accept my answer as it probably didn't help...

Comment: Well not solved my problem because my problem was me, but still, it was useful information which could help someone else in the future. Also I could not accept my own answer for 3 days and I'm not sure I will remember to come back and accept that one

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck with your Salesforce development!